# Two long text fields are "incompatible data types"

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am using an Access database which contains linked tables from SQL Server, I am creating a report using a subreport inside it, which I wish to pass a field by linking. The two fields in question are both long text is Access. In SQL Server they are both VARCHAR(MAX) data types.

Screenshot of error:

[image: Long Text and Long Text error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, plain and simple.

Access cannot link fields with data type "Long text" ("Memo" in earlier versions), not with local tables and not with linked SQL Server tables.

See also [Cannot join on Memo or OLE Object . (Error 3118)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb223620%28v=office.12%29.aspx) or
[Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object - Access 2007 - outer joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980535/cannot-join-on-memo-ole-or-hyperlink-object-access-2007-outer-joins)

IMHO, the need to do this is a sign of faulty table design. There should be an ID field to create the link.

Comment: Pity the error message is not as informative as you.  :-)  *“incompatible data types”* seems like weak explanation for this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will accept it as it answered my problem :) I would like to add however that I am not linking the tables in a literal sense, that is just what access calls what I am doing, the goal was to pass a variable from one table to another using the field link, it is now unnecessary as I used a filter on load instead.

Thank you